# SP 2010: How to print comments collected in workfloow, in email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, tasks, workflow-variable

I have setup my first SharePoint Foundation 2010 system but I have hit a wall with regards to a workflow I have created.

In the workflow, I collect two fields "Approval Status" and "Manager Notes," from a given user's manager. The problem is that I can't figure out how to reference the "Manager Notes" entered by the manager in the email to the user. I have tried to create a variable called "MGMTCommentVar" from the "Manager Notes," but I can't figure out the "Lookup for String" form. I have made the following selections: Data Source = Tasks, Field from source = Manager Notes, Return field as = Plain Text. The part that is throwing me is the "Find the List Item." All I want to do is print the "Manager Comments," collected in the task, inside an email. Everything I have tried has come up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task outputs a list item ID. Use that variable to look up to your task list to find the item and extract the comment field into a variable. Use that variable in your emails.

Comment: PirateEric, that answered my question perfectly. I really appreciate the fast response!

Comment: Your welcome, happy Sharepointing!